# How to vertically center my latex table cell

Tags: latex

My Latex tabular looks like this

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{clll}
\toprule
 \multirow{2}*{Name} & \multirow{2}*{Description} & \multicolumn{2}{c} 
  {Time}  \\
 \cline{3-4}  
   & & Item1 & Item2  \\
   \midrule
  App1 & Good & 1000ms  & 1000ms  \\

 \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
```

[image]'

I wonder how can I make `Item1` and `Item2` in the above table vertically-centered. Thank you!

Comment: can you please make a compilable [mre]?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Hi! I just edited it. Hope it is now easier to read)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the command `\cmidrule{3-4}`: it is equivalent to `\cline{3-4}`, but it improves the looking of the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{clll}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}*{Name} & \multirow{2}*{Description} & \multicolumn{2}{c} {Time}  \\
    \cmidrule{3-4}  
    & & Item1 & Item2  \\
    \midrule
    App1 & Good & 1000ms  & 1000ms  \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}  
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```